# Android AsyncTask error occurred doInBackground()

Tags: android, android-asynctask

```
 private class CreateGridTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private CreateGridTask() {
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voidArr) {
        GridView.this.grid.create(((WordSearchApplication) GridView.this.getContext().getApplicationContext()).getLexicon());
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void voidR) {
        GridView.this.startTime.setToNow();
        GridView.this.onGridReadyListener.onGridReady();
        GridView.this.invalidate();
    }
}

public interface OnGridReadyListener {
    void onGridReady();
}

public interface OnWordFoundListener {
    void onWordFound(Word word, int i);
}
```

Android Studio GridView error getting while doInBackground with AsyncTask method, where i done wrong in code pls and this

Comment: Do not do UI related commands in the doInBackground() method. If you really want to perform it on AsyncTask, do it on the onPreExcecute method

Answer (score 0):

You should not create the grid this way.

Instead, you should implement [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html). If cells have a number of particularly heavy operations, you may use AsyncTask within the adapter. Keep in mind, AsynTask starts a thread that is not attached to the UIThread and should not manipulate the UI until onPostExecute is called (Even then, use caution. Especially with a GridView where views may have been recycled)